# Arrange an expression based on variables' names

Tags: sorting, variable, expression

I have a problem of arranging an expression as shown in the following picture. The first expression `exp` is derived from other functions and equations. I want to get the result like (2) `expArranged`, which is formed from the constant, the functions of x1 and the functions of x2 in every terms of `exp`.

Can you give the approach to obtain the result? Thank you.

**Note**:

The name `expArranged` in expression (2) is only for the convenience to express my problem, not variable symbol.

The codes have been presented in the end of the post.

**Picture**

[image]

**Codes and the method converting it to standard form**

[image]

```
exp = a Subscript[Q, i][x1] Subscript[Q, j][x2] Subscript[Q, m][x1] Subscript[Q, n][x2] + b DiracDelta[x1] Subscript[Q, i][x1] Subscript[Q, j][x2] Subscript[Q, n][x2] Derivative[1][Subscript[Q, m]][x1] + c DiracDelta[x2] Subscript[Q, i][x1] Subscript[Q, j][x2] Subscript[Q, m][x1] Derivative[1][Subscript[Q, n]][x2] + d Subscript[Q, i][x1] Subscript[Q, j][x2] Subscript[Q, n][x2] (Subscript[Q, m]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x1];(*1*)
expArranged = {{a, Subscript[Q, i][x1] Subscript[Q, m][x1], Subscript[Q, j][x2] Subscript[Q, n][x2]}, {b, DiracDelta[x1] Subscript[Q, i][x1] Derivative[1][Subscript[Q, m]][ x1], Subscript[Q, j][x2] Subscript[Q, n][x2]}, {c, Subscript[Q, i][x1] Subscript[Q, m][x1], DiracDelta[x2] Subscript[Q, j][x2] Derivative[1][Subscript[Q, n]][ x2]}, {d, Subscript[Q, i][x1] (Subscript[Q, m]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x1], Subscript[Q, j][x2] Subscript[Q, n][x2]}};(*2*)
expArranged // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
(*end here*)
```

Comment: ```Times @@@ {Cases[#, Except[_[x1] | _[x2]]], Cases[#, _[x1]], Cases[#, _[x2]]} & /@ List @@ exp```

Comment: @Hausdorff, Thanks for your concise and excellent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eArranged = Values @ 
  GroupBy[SortBy[First[#, #] &] @ Apply[List] @ #, First[#, #] &, Times @@ # &] & /@ 
   MonomialList[exp];

eArranged // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Also

```
$p = Cases[x1 | x2];

eArranged2 = Times @@@ GatherBy[SortBy[List @@ ##, $p], $p] & /@ MonomialList[exp];

eArranged2 // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image]